# Open Source Xml Editor

Tags: c#, xml, xml-editor

I need to write a XML-based markup language. I'd like to provide an open source IDE for it, but I don't want to write it from scratch. So, I'm looking for an open source XML editor, written in C#, with WinForms or WPF UI, which I'll can extend it and add my markup language validation and etc, with the following features:

- XML Syntax Highlighting like VS
- Auto Completion
- Validation

It's license should be that I can edit it and then release it, with the source code.

Are there any things like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a good list:

- [DINAMIC XML Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dlxmleditor/)(Written all in C#)
- [Open eXeed](http://openexeed.sourceforge.jp/)
- [Serna Free - Open Source XML Editor](http://www.syntext.com/products/serna-free/)
- [XML Pro](http://www.vervet.com/)
- [Jaxe](http://jaxe.sourceforge.net/)
- [Xerlin](http://www.xerlin.org/)
- [Rose India - Open Source XML Editor](http://www.roseindia.net/opensource/open-source-xml-editor.shtml)
- [Open source XML editors examined](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/43020)
- [Re: Open Source XML Editor](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200102/msg00277.html)
- [Open Source XML Editor In Sight](http://lizards.opensuse.org/2009/06/18/open-source-xml-editor-in-sight/)
- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- [ViM](http://www.vim.org/)

Comment: Check tha first of the list ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Greg's Xml Editor](http://gregsxmleditor.codeplex.com/) is exactly what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What a waste of time, it's full of bugs like a document tree that grows whenever you click on it. The spelling errors like 'sintax error' provide some comedy value, but wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What would you recommend then?

Answer (score 1):

Try [XmlAutoComplete](http://xmlautocomplete.codeplex.com/) - WPF control, written in C#, Net4.0

Answer (score 0):

I use emacs. 
you can try sgml-mode or nxml-mode.

Comment: I just tried emacs then found that it can't validate using W3C XML Schema (xsd), only RELAX NG schema (rnc). Something worth noting.

Comment: ya - there's a separate question I posted here about that.